# Why my session is not restored after copying all the cookies from 1 pc to other?

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, microsoft-edge

So i know the cookies of edge is stored under **C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Network** so i copied the whole **Default** folder from my old computer to the new one.And when i visited youtube and instagram i had to relogin again. Why did this happen did i copied the wrong folder.Or is there any encryption like the cookies can only be read by the old computer.

If i copied the wrong folder, please state which folder to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't copy the wrong folder. It can't restore the session because the privacy related data is encrypted and it won't work even you copy & paste to the new device. I think that's due to security reasons.

I suggest that you can login Edge with the same profile as that in your old computer, so that you can directly use the saved username and password to login websites.